# How do I get the ID from url and use it to navigate to the next page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I am using apis to pull data on football teams. I am displaying a table of teams on one page but this data does not contain ids. When selecting a team I want to navigate to a page that displays more detail on the specific team. However the id of the teams are contained in the urls? e.g. http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/57 is for Manchester United. What do I need to do to select the team from the table and display their details?

Comment: Do you need 57?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes 57 is the ID I need

Comment: Try my answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes it does get the id but what I am wondering is I am looking to select a team from the table which does not contain the id. Do I need to save the api data to a database first?

Comment: Yes, make two columns in the database 1. Team ID 2. URL (API link). This will get you the desired results. And please mark the correct answer and upvote any useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

The fixtures are in the `href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/57/fixtures` and the players details in `href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/57/players`

You just need to handle those JSON data and extract whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just consuming the data from mentioned API then use this code,

```
 var idLength = url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) - 1;
 var id = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1, idLength);
```

I have used **2** by assuming the ID of the team is a **2 digit number**.

**Note: Updated my answer to accommodate the id of any length**